# .htaccess redirect to https if not http and add forward slash if it doesn't exist in one redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm having some trouble getting multiple redirect rules working in an .htaccess file without it causing a redirect chain:

First I want to force HTTPS

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```

Then I want to ensure a trailing slash is applied

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301]
```

However, I want to do these both as ONE redirect. So if a request comes in with:

```
http://example.com/page
```

in ONE 301 redirect it should give

```
https://example.com/page/
```

I'm using httpstatus.io to test the redirect chains. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with below,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks Abhishek. I believe the issue with this is that it will not redirect http://example.com/page/ to https://example.com/page/ as the second condition is not met.

Comment: You want it with trailing slash or without trailing slash because above is working for me for trailing slash.

Comment: I want it to always redirect to a trailing slash. So both redirects need to work independently and together.   http:// example.com/page /  (with the /) will skip the rule and not redirect to https.

Stackoverflow is turning my links in hyperlinks and removing the slash in my previous comment - sorry :)

Comment: It is working here http://htaccess.mwl.be as you wanted, you can confirm.

Comment: try with http : // test.com /

Comment: (minus the spaces)